# Changing inner-radius of tube-like object

Tags: 3d-printing

I imported a microscope adapter .stl file into Blender. The adapter has a tube like shape and I need to shorten the inner-radius of the adapter to suit my microscope, keeping the cuboid positions the same. How can this be done?

I want to avoid starting again from scratch since this component (found on Thingiverse @https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:214466) has been carefully engineered to fit the rest of the system.

[image: Microscope adapter in question]

Comment: Do you want to let the outer side remain in the same position?

Comment: @Akshay2005 Thanks for pointing that out, let the outer side remain in the same position

Comment: There are two smart techniques to select the inner faces in the answers, but consider the simplest technique: press [3] key for face selection mode and [C] key for a selection brush and then just draw on those faces to select them, there aren't that many of them. BTW, you might want to know that Catmull-Clark subdivision surface algorithm has a tendency to shrink a mesh (decrease the outer radius, increase the inner radius https://i.imgur.com/5bqoJyM.gif )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With everything selected hit ctl+J, this will turn the triangled faces into quads:
[image]
Then in face mode, press Alt + click on one of the vertical edges on the inside faces to select that loop
[image]
You can then hit S->Shift+Z to scale along the X and Y axis or Alt+S to move the faces along their normals. In this case both would do the same
To make it have a specific radius on the inside, the easiest thing to do would be to add another cylinder in the middle with the specific radius you want and use it as a reference when scaling.
If you are printing this remember to leave a bit of margin of error or it won't fit afterwards. Usually 0.4mm for FDM or 0.2/0.3 for resin (i.e make the reference cylinder's radius = 'radius you want' + 0.8 or 0.4/0.6)

Comment: *" the easiest thing to do would be to add another cylinder"* - how about this: look at a vertex lying on $x=0$ or $y=0$ plane, so one of the XY coordinates is 0. Now take the non-zero coordinate (without a unit), copy to clipboard, and scale by a reciprocal ($1\over x$) of it. Now the inner radius is $1$. To make it a specific radius just scale again this time setting the scale to the radius you need. https://i.imgur.com/PY0w52q.gif And if each vertex has both X and Y coordinate, you could open Python console to easily calculate current radius: `Vector((x, y)).length` (replace `x` and `y`)

Answer (score 2):

You can select all the vertices of the inner side and and scale them only on the X & Y-axis. To do this select all the vertices of the inner side (Trick: Go to top view and press for circle select. Then just scroll to increase the selection radius and select all the inner vertices and press enter). Then press S and shift+z to scale it only on the X & Y-axis according to your need.